# Specflow tests in parallel : PNunit - I don't want to have to specify every test in config

Tags: parallel-processing, nunit, specflow, pnunit

I have successfully got pNunit (http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/pnunit.aspx) working to run my specflow tests in parallel.

I really don't like the fact I have to specify that the specific tests I would like to run on each agent though. Tests change and are added frequently. I wouldn't want to have a test not run because someone forgot to update the config file.

In an ideal world, I would like to say Agent 1 would run Test fo Category A and Agent 2 would run Category 2.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at nCrunch? It will perform parallel test runs while you are editing, leaving you just to run normal nUnit on your build server. I use it daily with SpecFlow and normal nunit tests. No config updates necessary.

Comment: I Use NCrunch locally, but I was looking to speed up the tests on my CI server.

Comment: [SpecRun](http://specrun.net/) (from the creators of SpecFlow) gives you that (and more).

Comment: The binary example on the link you provided is broken. I'm unable to make the example work. Any idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220761/pnunit-binary-example-fails-running

Comment: You can try this my little project https://github.com/qakit/ParallelTestRunner , which was developed for same purposes. Works fine with local tests - not good yet with running tests on different machines (but still in development). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar need, on CI server, and were not happy with SpecRun, so we built our own tool for it.  https://github.com/uShip/Concord

We have it running 130 categories between 12 threads, both locally and server-side.  We also have it running selenium tests in parallel.

I personally never tried nCrunch or pNunit for specflow tests, but the guy who started this tool researched it for weeks before just starting this tool.  Then I helped enhance the tool for further needs.

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution that generates a nant build file, which uses nunit in a custom parallel nant task:

https://github.com/MartyIce/SpecflowParallelizer

Due to how my legacy tests were written, I get backend concurrency problems, so it hasn't been succesful for me (yet) but hopefully this will work for someone else.